# Gnome got autoremoved (18.04)

Tags: command-line, 18.04

After running apt update, I was prompted to run apt autoremove. I'd done this a few times before with no consequence, so I did. Immediately xterm closed, and I noticed gedit and the ubuntu store were both gone. I restarted my pc after a few minutes of trying to find a soultion, only for my pc to show a bare terminal. There's no graphics and anything I try to run tells me `X11 Display is not available`.

There's also no internet drivers it seems.

My personal files in the home folder are completely unchanged however.

Comment: You would have previously removed a requirement (*depends*) package that forced the removal of GNOME when `apt autoremove` was next run. If you look up your `apt` logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) you could find out what you removed by mistake (or without understanding what it's effect would be), or just re-install the packages you want.

Comment: @guiverc yup that seems to be it. I got it to do something, it showed the normal loading screenfor a bit but now I'm back to the terminal.

Comment: Try: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to restore your complete desktop. Not clear what you mean by "internet drivers". If you mean that your wifi stopped working, that's expected -- you likely removed NetworkManager. Plug into an ethernet cable, if available.

Comment: @user535733 thanks, this worked. I'd still like to know how something like this can happen though

Comment: @guiverc already told you how it happens, and told you how to find out the specifics of your case.

Comment: @user535733 I understand what happened, I'm just confused as I'm sure I didn't do anything other than ```apt update``` and ```apt autoremove```

Comment: Yes, you ran autoremove. That did it. You didn't read the proposed removals before agreeing -- that was the safety. Lesson: ALWAYS read your apt output before agreeing.